# 'ddpJobType' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: asp.net

im trying to bind the data from database to dropdownlist and i want to set the default value as "select". but i got this error.
My Code is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddpJobType" runat="server" Width="226px" Height="26px" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="ddpJobType_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" Text="--Please Select Type--"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please Select JobType "  Font-Size="Small" 
                    ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="ddpJobType" 
                    ValidationGroup="VGPJobPost"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are banding data using DataSource, then your default item will not be available after the call of DataBind function. You need to add it manually after calling databind something like below

```
dropDownList.DataSource= yourdataSource;
dropDownList.DataBind();
dropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Please Select Type--", "0"));
```

Another option is in the designer you need to specifiy

```
AppendDataBoundItems=true
```

This will make sure your designtime list items are present after databind

Comment: but im click on the cancel button it will show same error. ddpJobType.SelectedValue = "--Please Select Type--"; Please Reply soon